# Subtraction not working - Clojure

Tags: clojure, subtraction

I am trying to make a very simple Nim game that probably isn't even considered a proper implementation of Nim, but I am only starting Clojure.  Not sure why this subtraction on line four doesn't work...

```
   1. (def nimBoard 10)
   2. (println "There are" nimBoard "objects left")
   3. (def in (read-line))
   4. (- nimBoard in)
```

I can't seem to come up with a solid algorithm for asking the user if they want to remove one or two "objects" from the board until it is empty.  I am coming from Java, but loops in this language just confuse me a lot.  I know what I am trying to make isn't exactly the Game of Nim, but it is for practice.

I would appreciate any help:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `in` is a string you read from standard in, you need to convert `in` to a number first before the subtraction. Try this:

```
(defn parse-int [s]
      (Integer. (re-find  #"\d+" s )))
(- nimBoard (parse-int in))
```

Comment: Totally understand. When you are learning a new language, sometimes the little stuff slips through the cracks. I'm still learning Clojure too. Good luck with your studies!